# Setting up SJF in SLURM

Tags: slurm

I am new to SLURM and trying to look for config so that the priority of job is inversely proportional to the job completion time. In other words, shortest job should have more priority. I looked at the documentation but didn't found anything useful. I found out that I can setup QOS based on several parameters but that doesn't include job running time.

It would be great if someone can guide me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `PriorityType=priority/multifactor` plugin, there is no factor directly related to the (requested) job duration, but the `JobSize` factor [can be set](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html) to be

> based upon not the job size alone, but the job's size divided by it's
>   time limit.

by setting the `SMALL_RELATIVE_TO_TIME` flag. Make sure `PriorityWeightAge` is positive, and `PriorityFavorSmall` is correctly set based on your use case.

Another option is to create a QOS that offer a priority boost but [imposes a smaller maximum wall time](https://slurm.schedmd.com/resource_limits.html) (look for`GrpWall` and `MaxWallDurationPerJob` options). In that case, either have the user request the QOS at submission time, or write a `job_submit` plugin that adds the QOS when the requested wall time is below the limit.